# Comparing a variable to multiple values

Tags: c#

Quite often in my code I need to compare a variable to several values :

```
if ( type == BillType.Bill || type == BillType.Payment || type == BillType.Receipt )
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

I keep on thinking I can do :

```
if ( type in ( BillType.Bill, BillType.Payment, BillType.Receipt ) )
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

But of course thats SQL that allows this.

Is there a tidier way in C#?

Comment: languages like Python and Ruby have the "in" operator, too.

Comment: @Can Berk Güder : I have just been looking for this "in" operator in Ruby but cant find it or anything similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You could do with with `.Contains` like this:

```
if (new[] { BillType.Receipt, BillType.Bill, BillType.Payment}.Contains(type)) {}
```

Or, create your own extension method that does it with a more readable syntax

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsIn<T>(this T @this, params T[] possibles)
    {
        return possibles.Contains(@this);
    }
}
```

Then call it by:

```
if (type.IsIn(BillType.Receipt, BillType.Bill, BillType.Payment)) {}
```

Comment: Extension, definitely. I really think the `Enum` class should have a similar method to deal with this issue. Either that or the LINQ environment should add enum-related functions. Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 13):

There's also the switch statement

```
switch(type) {
    case BillType.Bill:
    case BillType.Payment:
    case BillType.Receipt:
        // Do stuff
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Assuming type is an enumeration, you could use the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx):

```
[Flags]
enum BillType
{
    None = 0,
    Bill = 2,
    Payment = 4,
    Receipt = 8
}

if ((type & (BillType.Bill | BillType.Payment | BillType.Receipt)) != 0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will only work for enums that havent had their values already defined. In this particular case our BillTypes have already been defined as 1-8... Sadly.. I like the neatness of this one..

Comment: I'd recommend reserving the FlagsAttribute for things that are, well, flags.  Decorating the BillType with `[Flags]` says to me that any combination of BillTypes can be applied to the value, which clearly isn't the case.

Comment: @Mike in that case why would the same thing need to be done to them. In a different system, a BillType may indeed be a flag. Although you are right, does seem like a code smell to me. I can take it down.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a switch

```
 switch (type)
    {
        case BillType.Bill:
        case BillType.Payment:

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using C# HashSet for list of values. This can be especially useful if you need to compare many values to single set of values.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the Strategy Design Pattern (a.k.a. the Policy Design Pattern).

```
public interface IBillTypePolicy
{
    public BillType { get; }
    void HandleBillType();
}
public class BillPolicy : IBillTypePolicy
{
    public BillType BillType { get { return BillType.Bill; } }

    public void HandleBillType() 
    { 
        // your code here...
    }
}
```

Here's a [great post on how to dynamically resolve the policy](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/sean_chambers/archive/2009/08/11/refactoring-day-11-switch-to-strategy.aspx) from Los Techies.

Comment: Good pattern, wrong problem.  This doesn't answer the original question!

Comment: I do see where youre coming from. Its a higher level solution to the problem and could be worth contemplating in some cases if Im putting lots of if statements all around the place.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting an array of all Enums values and iterate through this?

http://maniish.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/iterate-through-enumeration-c/