# C - Most succinct way to check if a variable is *none* of many options?

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison

**Background:**

Often, we developers must check if a single variable is at least one of many options. For example,

```
if ( (data == 125) || (data == 500) || (data == 750) )
{
    /* ... do stuff ...*/
}
```

The suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356949/comparing-a-variable-to-multiple-values) (albeit written in C#), provides an elegant solution to use a `switch` statement like so,

```
switch ( data )
{
    case 125:
    case 500:
    case 750:
        /* ... do stuff ...*/
        break;

    default:
        /* ... do nothing ... */
        break;
}
```

This works well for "or" conditionals, but is ugly for negated "or" conditionals like the following,

```
if ( !( (data == 125) || (data == 500) || (data == 750) ) )
{
    /* ... do stuff ...*/
}
```

which could be written as

```
switch ( data )
{
    case 125:
    case 500:
    case 750:
        /* ... do nothing ... */
        break;

    default:
        /* ... do stuff ...*/
        break;

}
```

and seems a bit hackish.

**Question:**

Is there a more succinct way to check if a single variable is *none* of many options, like the negated "or" conditional above?

**References:**

- [C++ Most efficient way to compare a variable to multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values)
- C# [Comparing a variable to multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356949/comparing-a-variable-to-multiple-values)

Comment: I rather like your last code example.  It's very clear what is happening there.

Comment: Is it "hackish" just because the work is done after the `default` label rather than in the fall-throughs? I wouldn't agree.

Comment: With such questions as to what is "most" or "best",  the best code style, best to maintain style, simplest source code, most portable, fastest, least source code, least executable code, least memory are competing factors.  Being explicit in term of coding goals helps arrive at the best answer.  "Most succinct" sounds like [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) which I am sure was not the intent.

Comment: I like your second example more as well. Given you provide a "do nothing" comment in the "excludes cases" (which you didn't) it's very clear what is going on - Not the least bit of 'hackish' IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @tofro, I've added your suggestion to improve the question clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the latter is fine.

You can formalize it better, though:

```
static bool in_sprawling_set(int data)
{
  switch ( data )
  {
    case 125:
    case 500:
    case 750:
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and then where you want to do the work:

```
if(!in_sprawling_set(data))
{
  /* do the work, not in set */
}
```

This puts the "in set" logic in a function of its own, makes it mildly self-documenting, and the actual use-place much cleaner since the `!` becomes more prominent and the final `if` is very readable ("if not in sprawling set").

Note: if the number of values is really large, I'd probably go for using a pre-sorted array and a binary search, rather than a huge `switch`. I realize a sufficiently clever compiler can do that transform by itself, but the readability of a huge `switch` would be rather low (especially if you like to put only one `case` per line). There's `bsearch()` for the searching:

```
static int cmp_int(const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
  const int a = *(const int *) ap, b = *(const int *) bp;
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b;
}

static bool in_sprawling_set(int data)
{
  static const int values[] = { 125, 500, 750 };
  return bsearch(&data, values, sizeof values / sizeof *values, sizeof *values, cmp_int) != 0;
}
```

There's quite a lot of boilerplate going on, but you can see how the part that lists the actual values (the only thing that'll grow as more values are added) is more compact.

Comment: Note, that by default GCC is warning about `cases` without `break`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Even if it ends with a `return`? Are you sure?

Comment: Umm.. Let me check.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is not. Was referring to a related issue, when you want to fall-through *after* doing some case-specific job, like `case A: doA(); case B: doB(); break;` instead of `case A: doAandB(); break; case B: doB(); break;`

Comment: Thanks for the response @unwind!  I think your solution is very elegant and particularly like the way you expanded the idea to anticipate large comparison sets in your note at the end.  Thanks, again!

Comment: I like your `bsearch()` approach for a large number of deflection cases. It does, however have the disadvantage over the `switch...case` approach that you cannot put the most probable deflection cases (if you have a probability) towards the beginning for speed. In such a case you would want to simply iterate through the array sorted by probability.

Comment: @tofro I don't think there's such a guarantee, that labels closer to the top of the `switch` will be reached faster. In practice perhaps, for certain compilers etc.

Comment: Nope, the standard makes no guarantee on that, right. Experience with various compilers, however, tells me it's most often the case (and actually, I can't see a lot of reasons why a compiler should re-shuffle the order of cases.) Supporting fall-thru obviously *requires* the compiler to keep the order, though. The proposed variation of your solution (iteration through an array sorted by priority), however, can never be changed by a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of negating the condition, you can always use De-morgans laws to simplify the expression

```
if (data != 125 && data != 500 && data != 750) ...
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a more succinct way to check if a single variable is none of many options?

The `switch()` statement is certainly a fine solution.

As an alternative, if the product does not over flow, code could use a single branch test:

```
unsigned data = foo();
if ( (data - 125) * (data - 500) * (data - 750) ) {
  /* ... do stuff as long as data is not 125, 500  or 750 ...*/
}
```

If it more clear - not really,  Is it faster than `switch()`? *it has potential*.

Comment: Very interesting alternative @chux.  This made me think more deeply about optimizing conditional speed and the implications for my project.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: What would be an advantage over the *compare+or* approach? I see none. Same number of terms and operators. In addition, the multiplication is not (necessarily) short-circuiting.

Comment: @Eric Schnipke When speed is important, then one should also consider the set of typical values of `data`.  Various approaches can be optimized to that set.  Are `125,500,750` rare or common?  I re-call [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) as tool to make fast parsers

Comment: @Eugene Sh. By " compare+or" I suppose you mean `(data == 125) || (data == 500) || (data == 750)` - that code can well cause multiple branches - this can be slow on pipelined processors.  Same with  `(data == 125) | (data == 500) | (data == 750)`. On pipelined processors, lack of short-circuiting is often faster. As in previous comment, speed comparison are affected by the set distribution of `data.  In the end - sometime a smart compiler will make optimal code given various source code.

Comment: @Eugene and Eric:  For speed on advanced processors, consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2410359

Comment: @Michael Smith Curious you find `if ( (data - 125) * (data - 500) * (data - 750) )` quite a bit more overhead than `switch ( data )
{
    case 125:
    case 500:
    case 750:
        break;

    default:
        /* ... do stuff ...*/
        break;

}`  OP' "Most succinct" could be taken as a request for a high performance solution versus a code golf.  Consider a non-branching solution adds value as commented by [OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104445/c-most-succinct-way-to-check-if-a-variable-is-none-of-many-options/38104852?noredirect=1#comment63643795_38104852)